# Передать данные на две страницы при отправке формы

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть обычная форма, которая при нажатии на Send переводит пользователя на сторонюю страницу, к которой я не имею доступа. Задача в том, чтобы перед переходом на эту страницу (или паралельно с переходом на нее) записать в БД данные, которые были заполнены в момент нажатия кнопки Send. Как такое можно реализовать? Спасибо.

Comment: аяксом можно. Пишете колбэк для $('form_selector').submit(event) в котором делаете асинхронный запрос к скрипту для записи в базу. При успешном ответе делаете return; , а при неудачном event.preventDefault()

Comment: вот [ссылка](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) на jquery функцию .submit()

Comment: Забыл спросить, у вас Send именно именно сабмитит форму?

Comment: да, форму сабмитит. но я, к сожалению, в аяксе не силен :(

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#testForm').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = false;
  
  var form = $(this); //делаем ссылку на элемент формы
  
  var sendingParam = $('#testValue').val();
  $.post('handler.php', {paramToSave: sendingParam}
        ,function(data) {
          //это обработчик успешного 
        }
        ,function(data) {
         //это обработчик неудачного запроса
        }
        ,function(data) {
          form.off('submit'); //освобождаем форму от текущего обработчика события submit
          form.submit();// чтобы вызвать стандартную функцию сабмита вместо той, что мы описали
        });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="formName" is="testForm">
  <input type="text" id="testValue" name="testValue"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Где handler.php - это ваш скрипт в котором находится функция сохранения в базу